# Can shift, rotate, and flip operations on a 2D matrix be combined into a single operation?

Tags: c, matrix, operations

Say I have a n by n matrix that has each cell as either a 0 or a 1. There is a list of commands that feed into a program. These commands specify an operation (shift, rotate, flip) and a value x, to specify the magnitude of the operation. The operation will only move cells with a 1 in it. A "UP 3" operation would cause all cells with "1" to shift up by 3.

In the case where there are multiple operations that must be sequentially applied to the matrix, for optimization, what I can do is combine contiguous operations of the same type. As in (up, down, left, right) would all be the same type (shift). CW and CCW rotations would be the same type. And Flip in the x or y directions would be the same type. I can combine multiple operations of the same type if they happen one after another. (i.e. UP 3, DOWN 2 -> results in a net UP 1). I want to know if there is a way to do a single "net" operation by combining operations of **different** types.

So I want to know, in my operations list, if I have for example, 1 UP, 1 CW, 3 RIGHT, 1 Y FLIP, 2 DOWN.

Instead of doing the above 6 instructions in 6 "moves", is there a mathematical/programming way to combine those into **a single** instruction for a square n by n matrix?

Must be do-able in C.

Comment: no, but you can use SIMD instructions if your architecture supports it.

Comment: @Rafael - huh? A common use of matrices is to perform precisely the operations requested. I.e One can transform from model-space to screen-space (an operation all 3d applications require) by multiplying the point by a single matrix. That matrix is composed by multiplying the matrices needed for each single operation into a single matrix. SIMD instructions have nothing to do with the question. Best you go (re?)read the math theory behind the process. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep While it's possible to use SIMD instructions to perform "simple" things like matrix multiplication as a small (almost single) operation. Doing all of shifting, rotation and flipping is hardly possible as a *single* operation. It can be made into a single *function call*, but then that function still have to do multiple operations.

Comment: @enhzflep I answered his question, you did not. He asked is it possible to do all those operations in a *single* instruction. His question is about optimization. I simply recommended SIMD instructions to achieve higher performance.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - I imagine you and I have different understandings of the use 'single operation' here. Multiplying a vector by a matrix is what I would characterise as a single operation. Once the matrix has been constructed, it is a single operation to apply it.

Comment: It sounds like he meant "single transformation."

Comment: @Rafael - indeed.

Comment: Yes there is...

Comment: IIRC, shift, rotate, and flip can be done in a single a single instruction for a square (n+1) by (n+1) matrix.  IOWs, n * n --> np1 * np1 --> single op --> n * n.

Comment: Don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, there is some confusion about the terminology, so let's clarify the terms.

Let's say you have a set of nine unique operations: `UP`, `DOWN`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `ROTATE+90`, `ROTATE+180`, `ROTATE+270`, `HFLIP`, and `VFLIP`. You have implemented each of these as a separate function, copying the contents of an N-by-N matrix to a new matrix.

(Also note that you cannot shift, rotate, or flip/mirror "only ones" in a matrix with only ones and zeros in it. If you try, the effect is the same as when you apply the operation to both ones and zeros. Try it, and you'll see.)

If I've understood correctly, the question can be restated as

> Is there a way to combine any sequence of those operations, so that I only need one double loop, rather than a double loop for each individual operation?

The answer is *Yes*, but the implementation is tricky, and there are two different ways the shifts (`UP`, `DOWN`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`) can operate, depending on whether elements that are "shifted out" appear from the other edge, or are lost. As an example, consider a `RIGHT` operation on a 4×4 matrix:

```
Horizontally periodic        nonperiodic
 0 0 1 0     0 0 0 1     0 0 1 0     0 0 0 1
 0 1 1 1  ⇒  1 0 1 1     0 1 1 1  ⇒  0 0 1 1
 0 0 1 0     0 0 0 1     0 0 1 0     0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0
```

The matrix can be nonperiodic, horizontally periodic, vertically periodic, or fully periodic (i.e., both horizontally and vertically periodic).

For simplicity, let's assume nonperiodic boundaries: The ones are lost, if they are shifted outside the matrix. Zeros are always "shifted in". (This is the easiest case.)

Any combination of the nine unique operations, in any order, even repeated, can be implemented using a single double loop:

```
For newrow = 1 to N:
    row = oldrow
    col = oldcol
    For newcol = 1 to N:
        If (row >= 1) and (row <= N) and
           (col >= 1) and (col <= N) and
           (oldmatrix[row][col] == 1):
            newmatrix[newrow][newcol] = 1
        Else:
            newmatrix[newrow][newcol] = 0
        End if
        row = row + colsteprow
        col = col + colstepcol
    End For
    oldrow = oldrow + rowsteprow
    oldcol = oldcol + rowstepcol
End For
```

As I said, this is a bit tricky. Think of superimposing the old and new matrices, but with the sequence of operations applied, and extending the old matrix (row and column numbers) to infinity. (Thus, the row and column numbers in the old matrix are no longer limited to 1..N, but can be any integer.)

You need to identify the row and column numbers (in the old matrix), that correspond to three elements in the new matrix: the first column in the first row, the second column in the first row, and the first column in the second row.

Let `row11` and `col11` identify the element in the old, infinite matrix, that coincides with the first column, first row in the new matrix; `row12` and `col12` the element that coincides with the second column, first row in the new matrix; and `row21`, `col21` the element that coincides with the first column, second row in the new matrix.

(In other words, you only need to track how your operations relocate/rotate/mirror these three cells in the old matrix. Hint: *reverse*.)

Then, at the beginning of the above pseudocode, set `oldrow = row11`, `oldcol = col11`, `colsteprow = row12 - row11`, `colstepcol = col12 - col11`, `rowsteprow = row21 - row11`, and `rowstepcol = col21 - col11`.

Essentially, `colsteprow` and `colstepcol` form an integer vector that tells us how an increment in the column number in the new matrix, corresponds to a change of row and/or column in the old matrix. (One of them will always be zero, and the other either +1 or -1.)

Similarly, `rowsteprow` and `rowstepcol` tells us how an increment in the row number in the new matrix corresponds to a change in row and/or column numbers in the old matrix.

If your matrix is horizontally periodic, then you wrap `oldcol == 0` to `oldcol = N`, and `oldcol == N+1` to `oldcol == 1`, and drop the If check for `oldcol`. Similarly, if your matrix is vertically periodic, then you wrap `oldrow == 0` to `oldrow = N`, and `oldrow == N+1` to `oldrow = 1`, and you drop the If check for `oldrow`.

If you find it hard to fathom how this works, get a transparent sheet of something, and draw a small grid on it, labeling each cell with the row and column numbers.  On a paper, draw a small matrix, with same sized cells. The operations shift, rotate, and mirror the transparent sheet on top of the paper.  Experiment and observe.

Comment: "Let row11 and col11 identify the element in the old, infinite matrix, that coincides with the first column, first row in the new matrix;"

Why do you have two terms? Why do you need TWO terms (row11 and col11) to define ONE element? I'm a bit confused by that. Usually when I refer to ONE element in the matrix I use something like elementXY, where X = row, Y = col

Comment: @Fuad: That is still two terms, one for *row*, and one for *column*. It is easier to handle them as separate variables.

Comment: @Bob: Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer? If this is indeed what you meant (combining successive shift, rotation, and flip/mirroring operations into a single double loop), I could edit your question a bit to rephrase it so that there would be no confusion. Just trying to help...